# How to process a large amount of in Java

Tags: java, performance

I have a requirement where I need to check each row of a value which is available in Database or Not in a Java Batch.

Here in my requirement,

I have a file which contains 200 rows of data at present perhaps this file might grow or shrink later for each n everyday.

The requirement here, i need to Insert and Update the reference table by checking the data from the file.

**Example File**

```
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

Emp No  Emp Name

1        Name-1   
2        Name-2
3        Name-3
4        Name-4
5        Name-5
6        Name-6
7        Name-7
8        Name-8
,,..... it goes on
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

I have a reference table (Standalone Table) which contains 2000 rows of data.

**For Example Emp Table**

```
******************************************************
Emp No Emp Name
1      Name-1
2      Name-2
3      Name-3
4      Name-4
5      Name-5
6      Name-6
7      Name-7
8      Name-8
,,..... it goes on
******************************************************
```

Currently a program is written in Java, where the data is fetched from the reference table and added to a Map with Emp Number as Key and Emp Details as value (Map).

Once it is added, then the data in file checked with Map using the key whether required data is available. if available then the data is updated or adding the new value to the Map.

Then finally batch insert is done.

***Here's my question whether this approach is good?***

Since I don't want to check the data with table each time, since i hope it is costly operation as the connection has to be open for long time.

But there is another costly thing, as far as now we have 2000 rows of data in the table this may be grow a large part of it even 10,000 (no surprise in it). Now here the issue hold large amount of data in the Map and processing it would be another hectic one right.

---

As both hits the performance issue in later stage

***What is the best way to manipulate such kind of requirement, is there any algorithm.***

---

Thanks in advance, could somebody give me a right direction in it.

Comment: Load the 200 rows and send a query to your database to upsert the data (if it supports it).

Comment: Loading 2000 records into memory seems like a worse idea than hitting the database 200 times.  You could consider breaking the file into chunks, so you take the first 20 records, do a DB retrieve, loop through the 20 to make your updates/inserts/ then push the 20 back in a batch update. Move onto your next 20 or so. This also helps mitigate failures so that if you fail at some point in the middle, you were at least partially successful during the batch.

Comment: These numbers are very low for you to worry about processing time.  Here's an article that describes how to do it in TSQL http://blogs.msdn.com/b/miah/archive/2008/02/17/sql-if-exists-update-else-insert.aspx  Essentially put that code in a stored proc and call the stored proc in a Java Batch.  Let the database do it's job... The hardest part is recovering from an error.  Some databases support upsert, so you need to do some research about which SQL is better for your server.  I routinely load data in batches between 1000 - 5000 records / batch.